# Does anyone know how to sync/open an already shared calendar on outlook for Mac onto my iCal?

Tags: ms-office, calendar, ical, exchange

Does anyone know how to sync/open an already shared calendar on outlook for Mac onto my iCal?
I have a shared calendar on my outlook for Mac (not Outlook 2016), but I need to open and sync that cal to my ical.

Comment: The native Calendar app? Isn't that already built in?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Apple Calendar. Select **Calendar** > **Preferences**.
2. Go to **Accounts**, and click the **+** icon on the bottom left.
3. Select **Exchange**, and enter your credentials.
4. That's it! Calendar will take care of the rest!